# Как в цикле присвоить формуле предыдущее значение

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Мне необходимо на С++ реализовать программу. Есть начальные значения *x<sub>1</sub>* и *x<sub>2</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>* и *y<sub>2</sub>*. Необходимо найти:

- *х<sub>3</sub> = ((у<sub>2</sub> - у<sub>1</sub>) / (х<sub>2</sub> - х<sub>1</sub>))<sup>2</sup> - х<sub>1</sub> - х<sub>2</sub>;*
- *у<sub>3</sub> = -у<sub>1</sub> + ((у<sub>2</sub> - у<sub>1</sub>) / (х<sub>2</sub> - х<sub>1</sub>))(x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>3</sub>).*

Далее нам необходимо найти *х<sub>4</sub>* и *у<sub>4</sub>* по тем же формулам, но

- *х<sub>4</sub> = ((у<sub>3</sub> - у<sub>1</sub>) / (х<sub>3</sub> - х<sub>1</sub>))<sup>2</sup> - х<sub>1</sub> - х<sub>3</sub>;*
- *у<sub>4</sub> = -у<sub>1</sub> + ((у<sub>3</sub> - у<sub>1</sub>) / (х<sub>3</sub> - х<sub>1</sub>))(x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>4</sub>).*

И так далее. Кто знает — пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Запоминайте в какой-нибудь переменной предыдущее значение....<br>
А вообще, если всё так как вы написали: `X ( N ) = ( N - 1 ) * X ( 0 ) + X ( 1 )`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!...это я привел простой пример...хотел применить предложенный алгоритм к своим сложным формулам... а их две...есть начальные значения Х1 и Х2, У1 и У2... необходимо найти х3 = ((у2-у1)/(х2-х1))^2 -х1 -х2..... у3= -у1 + ((у2-у1)/(х2-х1))*(x1-x3) вот, далее нам необходимо найти х4 и у4.... находится по тем же формулам,но х4= ((у3-у1)/(х3-х1))^2 -х1 -х3 ..... у4= -у1 + ((у3-у1)/(х3-х1))*(x1-x4) ....и так далее....

Answer (score 1):

Формула такая:

```
X[n] = ( ( Y[n-1] - Y[1] ) / ( X[n-1] - X[1] ) )^2 - X[1] - X[n-1]
Y[n]=  ( ( Y[n-1] - Y[1] ) / ( X[n-1] - X[1] ) ) ( X[1] - X[n] ) - Y[1]
```

n = 3+

Как-то так:

```
int n, max_n = 404;
double tmp, curr_x, curr_y,
       x1 = 1, x2 = 2,
       y1 = 1, y2 = 2,
       prev_x = x2,
       prev_y = y2;

for ( n = 0; n < max_n; n++ ){
  tmp = ( prev_y - y1 ) / ( prev_x - x1 );
  curr_x = tmp ^ 2 - x1 - prev_x;
  curr_y = tmp * ( x1 - curr_x ) - y1;

  //Делаете что хотите, например сохраняете в массиве

  prev_x = curr_x;
  prev_y = curr_y;
}
```

Comment: Да....формулы через n так...а вот как это на с++ реализовать...тут уже посложнее...
чтобы например ввели n=3......и прога посчитает y3 x3, потом у4 х4,потом х5 у5 и так далее

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! то,что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Что сложного?

```
int x=x1;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) x+=x0;
```

По комментарию выше. Это был вопрос? Если да, то отредактируй вопрос и добавь его туда.